# How to select the class embraced in the tag named "form-group"?

Tags: html, css, forms, label, pseudo-class

I have been creating a pop-up form for several hours. However I tried to select, I cannot opt the tag, label embraced the class tag named, "form-group". Actually, there is another class tag named label on the same HTML code file. I do not want to make a CSS effect on that.

```css
#contactModal {
  display: none;
  color: black;
}
.modal-body {
  color: black;
}
.form-group .label {
  color: #7c7c7c;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="level">*Which language and what Level- beginner, intermediate, advanced, or business level</label>
    <input type="text" name="level" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.form-group .label` applies to every tag with the class `label` that is a child of a tag with the class `form-group` but your label does not have the class `label`.
Therefore you either need to add that class or use the selector `.form-group > label` which applies to every tag of type `<label>` that is a child of a tag with class `form-group`.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the element you don't want to apply the css rules by adding a class on it. Check the code below.

HTML

```
<div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </form>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group exclude">
              <label for="level">*Which language and what Level- beginner, intermediate, advanced, or business level</label>
              <input type="text" name="level" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </form>
```

CSS

```
.form-group:not(.exclude) label {
  color: #7c7c7c;
}
```

This css rule would apply only to those `<label>` elements which are inside the `.form-group` element without the class `.exclude`